# How to differentiate between empty data and pending data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

In one of my templates I am doing the following:

```
{{#if controllers.nodesIndex}}
    {{outlet}}
{{else}}
    <div style="text-align:center;"><br/><br/><img src="images/circular_loader.gif" /><br/><br/>Loading your data...</div>
{{/if}}
```

I am showing a spinner while the data is loading. The problem is that this is not able to differentiate between the case when the server has not yet replied, and the case when the server has replied with an empty set.

How can I verify in the controller (or somewhere else) if the data has arrived?

Comment: Just set a property 'isLoading' to true, when a ajax call is made and set it back to false in .always()... if you are using ember data this will be available for you

Comment: The central ajax call can be triggered by lots of different actions (find, findAll, on different routes, record updates, etc). I want to know when  a *specific* request, related to a given template/controller/view has completed. A generic `isLoading` will not help me here. How can I be notified when a certain request related to a certain route has been completed?